# Keep checking for selector, click pagination if not found

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to setup a CasperJS script that will do some testing on a personal site.

I need to check for a selector, and if it cannot be found on the page, click the next page link in the pagination and check again.

I am struggling to wrap my head around this problem and how to solve it. I know I need some sort of loop, and I even tried a while() loop, but I don't understand CasperJS enough to get it working.

Basic idea of what I want, in psuedocode:

```
open page http://www.example.com

check if 'li.my-class' exists

if not
    click '.next-page'
    then check again for 'li.my-class'
    (repeat this process)
else
    'li.my-class' exists, go do something else
```

I've tried reading about waitFor, waitforSelector etc. The documentation doesn't help me much as it's quite basic in terms of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **recursion**, especially a **recursive IIFE**. Here is the implementation:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.example.com');

(function go() {
  casper.wait(1000, function () {
    if (!this.exists('li.my-class')) {
      this.click('.next-page');
      go();
    } else {
      // Do something...
    }
  });
})();

casper.run();
```

Comment: How do you trigger the `go()` method initially?

Comment: `go()` is a named IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression). Look at the syntax: `(function go() { /* ... */ })();`. Did you try the code?

Comment: Afraid not sorry! I will try and get round to trying it, as this unfortunately got shelved for the time being :)